# Reading data from a particular location of a FileStream using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read data from a file stream as shown below:

```
fileStream.Read(byteArray, offset, length);
```

The problem is that my offset and length are Unsigned Ints and above function accepts only ints. If I typecast to int, I am getting a negative value for offset which is meaningless and not acceptable by the function.

The offset and length are originally taken from another byte array as shown below:

```
BitConverter.ToUInt32(length, 0); //length is a 4 byte long byte-array
```

What is the right way to read from arbitrary locations of a file stream.

Comment: Basically you're using `FileStream.Read` wrong. Elisha posted what looks like to be the correct answer you need. If you do have an array >2GB, you need to rethink this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle it, but you can change the position of the stream and use offset 0. The [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position(v=VS.90).aspx) is of type `long`.

```
fileStream.Position = (long)length;
fileStream.Read(byteArray, 0, sizeToRead);
```

Answer (score 1):

For such a filesize you should read your file in small blocks, proccess the block and read the next. int.MaxValue is about ~2GB, uint.MaxValue ~4GB. Such a size doesn't fit in most computers ram ;)

Comment: Exactly. 640K - erm - 1GB ought to be enough for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having problems with conversion, something similar might help:

```
    uint myUInt;
    int i = (int)myUInt; or
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myUInt);
```